# Python: Trying to make 2 different shapes in the same file

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Hello I'm new to python and I'm trying to make two different shapes with turtle.

```
import turtle
from turtle import 
color('blue', 'red')
begin_fill()
while True:
    turtle.fd(150)
    turtle.left(144)
    if abs(pos()) < 1:
        break
end_fill()
done()
```

I have this first which works corectly, but I'm trying to make a circle around it, but I can't seem to even make one, with this:

```
color('blue', 'red')
begin_fill()
while True:
    turtle.circle(555)
    if abs(pos()) < 1:
        break
end_fill()
done()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't seem to even make one"? Your code works fine, it just doesn't draw the circle encircling the star. Is that what you want?

Comment: If you are simply adding the second block of code to the first, it won't do anything because of the `done()` at the end of the first block. As mentioned above your code draws a circle just fine, just not around the star.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
import turtle
from turtle import *
color('blue', 'red')
begin_fill()
while True:
    turtle.fd(150)
    turtle.left(144)
    if abs(pos()) < 1:
        break

end_fill()
turtle.penup()
turtle.sety(25)
turtle.setx(-1.2)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.circle(78)
done()
```

My calculations went wrong by a few decimals I think. But I suppose this should give you an idea.

[image]

Also in your code, I see that you have used a while loop to draw a circle. Your thinking is correct that you need to break the circle drawing but the `circle` function takes care of this and automatically stop once it reaches the starting position. Notice I have used the circle function without using any loop.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I didn't know about some of the commands you used, I get what they do now.

Answer (score 0):

Realizing that `turtle.circle()` is a regular polygon drawing routine, we can go much simpler:

```
import turtle

turtle.color('blue', 'red')

turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.circle(79, extent=720, steps=5)
turtle.end_fill()

turtle.circle(79)

turtle.done()
```

[image]

Or, if you want to stick with your current algorithm, we can do:

```
import turtle

turtle.color('blue', 'red')

turtle.begin_fill()
while True:
    turtle.fd(150)
    turtle.left(144)
    if abs(turtle.pos()) < 1:
        break
turtle.end_fill()

turtle.setheading(-69)

while True:
    turtle.fd(8.25)
    turtle.left(6)
    if abs(turtle.pos()) < 1:
        break

turtle.done()
```

[image]